# MySQL Simplifying JOINS, Date Functions

Tags: mysql, sql

My question is how to find my track titles of all tracks recorded by my artists which were entered into the database (that is, have entrydates) after September 1, 2003.

My Artists, Tracks, and Titles are related by certain IDs. The tables are as follows:

```
Artists
-------
ArtistID, Artistname, Entrydate

Tracks
------
TitleID, TrackNum, TrackTitle

Titles
------
TitleID, ArtistID, Title
```

I have formulated the following query:

```
SELECT tracktitle 
FROM   tracks tr 
       JOIN titles ti 
         ON ti.titleid = tr.titleid 
       JOIN artists ar 
         ON ar.artistid = ti.artistid 
WHERE  Year(ar.entrydate) >= 2003 
       AND Month(ar.entrydate) >= 9 
       AND Day(ar.entrydate) >= 1;
```

Is there a more efficient way of finding these track titles that are recorded (that is, have entry dates) after Sepetember 1, 2003?

Comment: What is the data type of `entrydate`? datetime, varchar?

Comment: The records resemble dates similar (but not exactly) to: 1/30/2010 and could be empty, that is NULL or null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ar.entrydate  >= "2003-09-01"` is enough if your field's data type is date. If its a timestamp field then `date(ar.entrydate)>="2003-09-01"`.

Comment: Yes, that comparision is what I was looking for. Also, would you think the query to answer my question is logical?

Answer (score 1):

Find the trackTitles of all tracks recorded by artists which were entered into the database (that is, have entrydates) after September 1, 2003.  Use one or more joins; 
do *not* use any subqueries.